# Reading data from JSON file and passing to data frame

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file `data.json` which contains large tweeter records. I am trying to load this JSON file to Jupyter and then transfer to a pandas data frame for further analysis. So far I have written the following code:
sample of tweets are `'{"_id":{"$oid":"5ec248611c9b498cdbf095a1"},"created_at":"Mon Dec 31 23:19:39 +0000 2018","id":{"$numberLong":"1079879790738325504"},"id_str":"1079879790738325504","text":"NPAF's Artist in Residence, Composer Glenn McClure is at the Park at work on his unusual sonification compostions`

```py
import json
import csv
json_file = "\\Users\\data.json"
header = ["id_str", "created_at", "lang", "text"]
tweets_processed = 0
with open(json_file, 'r') as infile:
    print("json file: ", json_file)
    
    for line in infile:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        
        #row = [tweet['id_str'], tweet['created_at'], tweet['lang'], tweet['text']]
        
       #csvwriter.writerow(row)
        
        tweets_processed += 1
        
#print("tweet processed: ", tweet_processed)
```

This is the code so far I have written basically to read my json file and pass it to pandas dataframe. Any help on how to get my json data into pandas dataframe? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried importing pandas and using its `read_json` function?

Comment: Yes, tried but did not work and getting error 'ValueError: Trailing data'

Comment: That's an interesting problem that we could look at. You could post a small example tweets file that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Ok. I updated my question and added sample of tweets

Comment: You don't want to write a csv file, so what is ` csvwriter.writerow(row)` intended to accomplish?

Comment: I further simplified my question. please have a look at it.

Comment: Post a *valid* sample of `data.json` with couple of tweets that work with your code.  Since you are reading line-by-line, is the data actually [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format?

Comment: The sample data, I added in my question, please do have a look at it.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath The sample is *not* valid JSON text.  Please correct it.  Provide a `data.json` sample that works with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You never imported the name csvwriter name into the namespace.

In this instance, you should likely be using csv.writer.writerow(). Alternatively, if you are trying to use the csvwriter package (which I doubt you are trying to do, then you need to add `import csvwriter` to the top of the file.

The takeaway is to read the docs of the package you are trying to use and importing everything into the proper namspace.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is use  pandas own function read_json().

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_json('file.json')
```

[image]

**File must contain format like this**

[image]

Comment: I think it may work with ur data. But in datasets, this is not working. I have tweeter datasets. And, when I run ur code, I m getting following error 'ValueError: Trailing data'

Comment: I added a sample of my datasets. Have a look at it let me know can u help me with this.

Comment: this error occur when your json file does not start with square brackets " [ " and end with " ] ".

Comment: my data start with '{' and end with '}'

Comment: So how to modify the above code where it can take square bracket?

Comment: I check your sample dataset, I gives error in pd.read_json() but when when I convert in correct format it run successfully. you can use this function only if your json file is in correct format according to standard.

Comment: At the beginning of file put   [      and   at the end of file  put      ]        save and    then check. for example i update my answer for correct format check it.